# Add facet to all modules

Tags: intellij-idea, infinitest

I wanted to start using Infinitest in IDEA.

[User guide](https://infinitest.github.io/doc/user_guide.html) tells you to add an "Infinitest" facet to your module. This is a bit of a problem since the project I'm working with has ~ 30 maven modules. I don't want to go over each one of them and manuall add the facet.

I've tried selecting all modules in the modules view, but when I click the green plus icon and select "Infinitest" it still only adds it to one module.

Please tell me there is some way to add it to all modules in bulk.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of any today. Better support for multi module in IntelliJ is definitevely on the things to do. And they are already several issues tracking problems with large set of modules: https://github.com/infinitest/infinitest/issues/173, https://github.com/infinitest/infinitest/issues/237, https://github.com/infinitest/infinitest/issues/29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't know of any today.

Better support for multi module in IntelliJ is definitevely on the things to do.

And they are already several issues tracking problems with large set of modules:

- https://github.com/infinitest/infinitest/issues/173
- https://github.com/infinitest/infinitest/issues/237
- https://github.com/infinitest/infinitest/issues/29